Story with a character called "the Haitian"?
This was somewhere in the 2008-2009 time frame. I'm pretty sure my dad gave me this book after he read it, and he read a lot of Clive Cussler-esque books (i.e., adventure possibly including sci-fi elements).
The main thing I remember is that there was a scene where some characters were either waiting for or introducing another character who they called "the Haitian". One of the characters responded by asking "what kind of -nese is he?" or something similar, in the sense that she thought he was called "the Asian" instead of "Haitian".
This might be me confusing this with other books I read at the same time, but I want to say the story was about finding Atlantis.

Just stating an obvious parallel, "The Haitian" was one of the villains in the Heroes TV series.

Interesting, maybe I'm misremembering it being from a book then! I did watch a couple seasons of Heroes while I was in high school. I'll have to check it out to see.

^_^ I don't think there was any Atlantis in the series, though.

I vaguely remember "The Haitian" being in a minor character in one of Lee Child's "Reacher" books.  But if so there's no SF involved.

@FuzzyBoots, I don't think so either. I tried searching a bit, I'm pretty sure it wasn't Heroes.

@Ethan That's also a possibility, my dad definitely read the Reacher books too. I might be misremembering there being scifi aspects. Do you remember which book/books that would've been? I'll try searching.

Could this be Clive Cussler's "Atlantis Found" (1999)? This would certainly fit the Clive Cussler-esque books category AND it is about trying to find Atlantis.
It has plenty of subtle sci-fi themes such as giant hidden ark style ships to survive an impending apocalypse, people who share identical DNA but aren't related, and secret cults whose members have very long life spans.
I don't remember all of the characters in this book but there was a Haitian assassin in another Clive Cussler book called "Piranha".
Could you have merged the two stories together?

This is a possibility. I'll have to check it out (and I might actually have it somewhere since I also have "The Hunt for Atlantis" from the other post ‍♂️)

If it is Cussler-esque rather than actual Cussler, then I'd suggest "The Hunt for Atlantis" by Andy McDermott.
This was the first of his Nina WIlde & Eddie Chase series, and funnily enough it happens to be about them hunting for Atlantis.
The character and the bad pun sound like his style.

I just checked, and I actually have this on one of my bookshelves haha. I'm going to check through some of it to see if I can find "the Haitian" somewhere
